# systemd: during startup of a service see messages

Tags: linux, services, systemd

I was using SysV for my service.

I had:

```
service myservice restart
```

Now migrating to systemd, and I like it more.
The only downside is that:

```
systemctl restart myservice
```

doesn't show the standard output of my service, that indicates progress.

I know I can use:

```
journalctl -u myservice -f -b
```

but I need another console for that, and it isn't a confortable solution.
Also `journalctl` doesn't stop when the service has finished its startup.

Any ideas for improving this?

*UPDATE*

My goal is to get the old SysV behaviour: when starting the service, show console output till the service startup is finished.  In this way, it can be known if there are some startup problems or to know the progress.  It can be sometimes slow to startup.

Comment: `systemctl status myservice`

Comment: So you propose:
`systemctl start myservice&; systemctl status myservice`
But how can I stop seeing messages when startup is finished?

Comment: In addition, `systemctl status myservice`, doesn't follow new messages.  I think it is better `journalctl -f`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want. If you just want to check for `active (running)` status, then `systemctl status myservice` is sufficient. The `active (running)` status usually means, that the service is serving its purpose.

If you require more simple test for service activity, you may use:

```
# systemctl is-active myservice
active
# echo $?
0
```

The faulty state may be:
    # systemctl is-active myservice
    inactive
    # echo $?
    3

So you may use it in the test.

---

However if you really require `journalctl -f` and you want to stop it after some time, you may use `timeout` command. See the example:

```
timeout 20s journalctl -f
```

The journalctl proces will be killed after 20 seconds in this example. If you redirect the output, you may parse it then.